# Spring Integration - specify 'schema' in StoredProcPollingChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-integration

How do I set the schema when using `StoredProcPollingChannelAdapter`? I do have 2 to 3 schemas on the same database connection object and the traditional "schema"."stored_proc" reference does not seem to work when using `StoredProcPollingChannelAdapter`

Comment: What is an error, please? Perhaps you can configure several data sources pointing to those schemas from their connection, so you won't need to use extra schema prefix in the procedure name...

Comment: Thx for quick response, please allow me a day to get back on the error or incorrect behavior when tried traditionally "schema"."stored_prod"

Comment: Did you try just like this `schema.stored_prod` ?

Comment: Yes, since there was no method available to set the schema but only the stored_proc name

Comment: Just FYI, this is the error throw --> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature for 'SCHEMA.STORED_PROC' - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName("SCHEMA")'

Comment: Ok. I think that JIRA ticket must be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I two words this is not supported as clean as possible at the moment.
We have an old JIRA ticket to see what and how is possible: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3348.

As a workaround I would suggest to go directly with the `SimpleJdbcCall` wrapped into some `MessageSource` instead of that `StoredProcPollingChannelAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, we shall try with the `SimpleJdbcCall` as suggested.